# Script editor in Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere

Is it possible to integrate an editor for voiceover texts and other scripts into Premiere Pro CC? Adobe Story will discontinue this year.

I do not mean texts sticking to a clip or a time in the sequence. This can be done using markers or titles. The editor should be independent of clips and exact seconds as this can change while the voiceover text stays the same.

A perfect editor would stick text to a clip but keep it when the clip is replaced later. But a very simple text editor would be enough.

At the moment I open my texts in a separate window while every other function is integrated into Premiere Pro. While speaking voiceover, the mouse and eyes jump between the controls and preview in Premiere and the editor on the other screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatley no. Adobe Premiere dropped what would have been your best possible “tool” when CC replaced CS6.

CS6 has a tool called Analyze Speech, used primarily for automated transcribing.

This tool could be used to substitute a rolling message box within the MetaData Window, tied to Key Frames. So you could use it manually in that sense to drop in a script and change the timings.

**Your Best Bet** is to either use basic slates/titles using the titler window. You could try playing with the rolling title feature, making a single rolling slate the length of your program... Or just block it out.

I do a ton of VO heavy productions however, and have never really thought of this as being an issue, even with CS6.

Not sure what your workflow is. But just recording a scratch track of your VO and dropping in temporary slates to indicate the placement of graphics, future media, tittles, etc, should get you there.